# session variable doesnt refreshing after UPDATE

Tags: php

I have a problem that had never happened before. My session variable "saldo" does not refreshing on the .php page. It is updated in the database after an UPDATE. But the variable is only refreshed if I log out and re-enter. What is the problem?

These are my session pages

```
//init.php
<?php   
session_start(); 
mysql_connect('localhost','root','usbw');   
mysql_select_db('cern_cn');     
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon'); 

?>
```

---

```
//login.php
<?php   
include ('init.php');
include ('con_cern_db.php');    
session_regenerate_id();

//CONSULTA DO UTILIZADOR    
$consulta="Select * from login where username='" . $_POST['username'] . "' and password='" . $_POST['password'] . "' AND saldo AND id";     
$resultado=mysql_query($consulta);  

if (mysql_num_rows($resultado)>0) //SE O EMAIL E A PASSWORD COINCIDIREM     
{       
    //COLOCA NA VARIAVEL LINHA OS DADOS DA CONSULTA         
    $linha=mysql_fetch_array($resultado); 
    //COLOCA O EMAIL EM SESSAO 

    $_SESSION['username']=$linha['username'];
    $username=$_SESSION['username'];

    $_SESSION['modo']=$linha['modo'];

    $_SESSION['saldo']=$linha['saldo'];
    $saldo=$_SESSION['saldo'];

    $_SESSION['id']=$linha['id'];
    $id=$_SESSION['id'];

    //REDIRECCIONA A PAGINA PARA A PAGINA SECRETA       
    header("location: index.php");      
}   
else //CASO NAO COINCIDAM   
{   
    //REDIRECCIONA PARA A PAGINA INICIAL REPORTANDO O ERRO
    header("location: index.php?erro=1");  
}        
?>
```

Calling data

```
<?php            

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) //SE EXISTIR AUTENTICAÇÃO            
 {              

    echo ' Olá ' . $_SESSION['username'] . '.<br/>';        

    echo '  ' . $_SESSION['saldo'] . '.Créditos<br/>';          
    //echo ' Modo ' . $_SESSION['modo'] . '.<br/>';     
   echo " ";

    //--------------------------//              
    //TODO O CODIGO PRIVADO AQUI//              
    //--------------------------//                               

}             
else //CASO NÃO ESTEJA AUTENTICADO             
{               
    echo 'Esta é uma àrea reservada, só utilizadores podem ter acesso.';             
 }      
?>
```

---

```
//logout.php
<?php   
include ('init.php');   
session_destroy();  
header("location: index.php"); 
?>
```

Comment: Unless you are using the database as session handler (eg. explicitly overriding the default session handler), you will need to re-assign the session variables after the update. From the code you provide, I can only assume that you only assign the session variable during the login.

Comment: hello my friend, thank u for answer. Can u explain how can i do the assignment?

Comment: When you do the update query, you should call another `session_start()` and just do the usual assignment. For example if you update your database from a form `$_SESSION['saldo'] = $_POST['saldo'];`

Comment: I create new files with only sessions system. and i change the $_SESSION['saldo'] directly from database next i do F5 and still doesnt refresh. only after logout login

Comment: Can you show the part where you do that.